# How to configure Android Media player to never play over speaker

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, media-player

I am creating Media Player, but it should never play on Speaker. If head phone jack or bluetooth is not available, still Audio should not be played over speaker.

I used below Android API but it still plays over speaker:

```
    AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    am.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
```

Comment: i am also creating a music app but never get this type of problem. My suggestion try your application in another device may be it is the device problem instead of your code

Answer (score 1):

You can check the whether Bluetooth and headphone connected or not by using Broadcast receiver using this link  http://blog.urvatechlabs.com/detect-programatically-if-headphone-or-bluetooth-headsets-attached-with-android-phone/ . If it is not connected/removed pause/stop the Android Media Player.

Comment: If your link provide the answer for the question, then post your answer here and give the link address for further information

Answer (score 1):

From [AudioManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager) official documentation

```
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(boolean)
```

> Sets the speakerphone on or off.

It means if you set the false it will disable the speaker sound i.e playing out from the speaker and if you set true it will play from the speaker.

In your case, you don't want to play your music from the outer speaker but still your using the `am.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);` which is actually enables the outer speaker.

So `set am.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);` so that it won't play the music from outer speaker

You can also set the Mode ( Call / Voice Communication / Music etc) for your AudioManager

```
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

**Note::**  For changing the audio manager settings you need to set `Permission: MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS` in manifest

add this line in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

In additional, this is the code to check which type of audio conncection

```
   AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
  PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();

  if (audioManager.isBluetoothA2dpOn()) {
    // Adjust output for Bluetooth.
    Log.d("debug","BluetoothA2dpOn");
  } else if (audioManager.isBluetoothScoOn()) {
    // Adjust output for Bluetooth of sco.
           Log.d("debug","BluetoothScoOn");
  } else if (audioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn()) {
    // Adjust output for headsets
       Log.d("debug","WiredHeadsetOn");
  } else if (audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn()) {
    // Adjust output for Speakerphone.
    Log.d("debug","SpeakerphoneOn");

  } else if (packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT)) {
    // Has internal speaker or other form of audio output.
               Log.d("debug","Internal Speaker On");

  } else {
    // No device for audio output.
    Log.d("debug","No Audio Device");

  }
```

Comment: I used am.setSpeakerphoneOn(false); and also <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />, but still can listen audio on speaker